# How to count number keys in array which have the same name

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count, array-key

For a flat file blog system, i have some `txt` files in a direcory `data/articles`.
A txt file looks like this:

```
id_20200430223049                    // id
Friends                              // category
uploads/mainimage_5eab357970b0d.jpeg // image
Officials wanted                     // title
comment<br />comment<br />comment    // comment
```

How can i count the number of categories for each category for all the txt files?

So lets say: i have **6** text files. On the 2nd line of each file:

2 of them have category **Club**

2 of them have category **Colleagues**

1 has category **Family**

and 1 has category **Friends**

What i have so far:

```
$files = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // Specify the file directory by extension (.txt)
$cat_lines = array();
foreach($files as $file) {

        $lines = file($file); // all lines of file in array
        $cat_lines[] = strtolower($lines[1]); // grab the category lines and put in array

}
```

`print_r($cat_lines);` gives me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => friends [1] => family [2] => club [3] => colleagues [4] => club [5] => colleagues )
```

To count the numbers of the keys in the array i use:

```
echo count (array_keys( $cat_lines, strtolower("Club") ) );
```

Unfortunatley, it gives me **0** as output instead of **2**!!! I dont' understand this...

But besides of this, what i finally want to achieve: How can i create a foreach loop that gives me an output like this:

```
Friends (1)
Family (1)
Club (2)
Colleagues (2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your items in `$lines` have linebreak symbols. This means that `club` is not the same as `club\n`.

Use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` when you use `file()` or trim value explicitly:

```
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of file in array WITHOUT linebreaks
```

As for your second question - [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/array_count_values) will give you new array with counts of every element in it:

```
$counts = array_count_values($cat_lines);
```

Comment: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` now gives me **2**.  Super solution! And i agree, the new array `counts` was exactly where is was looking for. Thnx for this solution!